# UITabbarController inside UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

iam trying to make a `UITbarbarController` inside `UISplitViewController` 
 [image]

when making this segue modal it hides the MasterViewController ,when making it push Segue  after reading apple Document we can't put UITabbarController inside UINavigationController,when i make the segue replace it doesn't animate and i cant dismiss the viewController anymore....
what is the best way to achieve this ?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want the initial detail view controller also to be in the tab bar controller, so you can make the tab bar controller the root detail controller?

Comment: G'Day hazem,  How did you go with this.  I am also trying get this to work.